# Determine if a varchar has upper and lower character with collation Latin1_CP_CI_AS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem and had a look on internet. First i found a solution but it seems to not work in all case. I cannot understand why.

Here is my problem, i'm working with a collation not case sensitive, i cannot change the collation of my column to use case sensitive on this column.

Here is a sample and my test :

```
declare @passcap varchar(30)= 'Chanel04O!' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS

select case when binary_checksum(lower(@passcap)) <> binary_checksum(@passcap) and binary_checksum(UPPER(@passcap)) <> binary_checksum(@passcap) then 1 else 0 end as pass_cap
, binary_checksum(lower(@passcap)), binary_checksum(@passcap)
```

And the result should be 1 of course cause the C and the O are upper case. but i receive a 0.

So i tried to execute the binary_checksum and i receive the same value for lower or normal : 2017408143

But why ? i found what is the problem, i have numbers and extra character (!).

I could imagine to do a regex only taking the character then comparing with a binary_checksum but is there something more proper?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the `UPPER` and `LOWER` values of the string to the original string, specificying the `Latin1_General_CS_AS` collation for the purposes of the comparison:

```
SELECT  CASE
          WHEN @passcap = UPPER(@passcap) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 0
          WHEN @passcap = LOWER(@passcap) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 0
          ELSE 1
        END
```

Therefore, 0 will be returned if the `UPPER` or `LOWER` version of the string match, otherwise if neither match then 1 will be returned.

Note that the case-sensitive collation is only used for the comparison of the strings, so no modification of your table is necessary.

Comment: Just tested with sql server 2014 and it works. It's strange because what i tested before posting is declare @passcap varchar(30)= 'Chanel04O!' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS and it doesn't work.